# No ionic o provider agora é Service?

Tags: ionic

Estou trabalhando em dois projetos, em um não funciona gerar provider e no outro não funciona gerar service. Alguém pode me dizer a diferença? O que devo mudar para ficar no mais recente? service é o mais recente? Qual pacote ou versão devo usar?

Answer (score 3):

No Ionic, pelo menos na versão 3, se usa o `Provider`, mas ambos são a mesma coisa. Isso é apenas uma convenção utilizada no *framework*. Tanto `Provider` como `Service` usam o mesmo decorator para injeção de dependências.

`import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';`

Se você tentar gerar um service utilizando o Ionic CLI, vai acontecer o seguinte:

```
$ ionic generate service test
[ERROR] type must be one of: component, directive, page, pipe, provider, tabs (not service)
Use the --help flag for more details.
```

Ele não reconhece service como um parâmetro para o comando.

Ps: Na versão 4 é possível usar service como parâmetro, como foi dito na outra resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Na prática, ambos possuem a mesma funcionalidade mas no Ionic 4 ele adota a nomenclatura de `Service`, enquanto no Ionic 3, ele é chamado de `Provider`.

De diferenças, no Ionic 3, o arquivo gerado é `nomedoprovider.ts`, já no Ionic 4 seria `nomedoservico.service.ts`.

Se você está querendo usar o código de um `Provider` no Ionic 4, você precisa modificar o decorador da classe `@Injectable()` para:

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Sobre qual usar, mesmo no Ionic 3, eu crio meus `Providers` com a mesma nomenclatura de um `Service`, apenas por questão de preferência. Sobre qual versão usar, eu sugiro [esse post](https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic-4-vs-ionic-3) (em inglês) e [esse](https://medium.com/learn-ionic-framework/ionic-4-vs-ionic-3-todo-lo-que-necesitas-saber-sobre-ionic-4-5235927c6dd9) (em espanhol) que diz um pouco das diferenças entre as versões.

Se quiser se aprofundar mais sobre como migrar do Ionic 3 para o 4, sugiro a própria [documentação oficial de migração](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/migration) (em inglês) do Ionic.