# Como instalar provider ?? Ionic 4

Tags: ionic, firebase, angularjs-services, angular-providers

Não consigo de jeito nenhum instalar esse provider , ele pede para gerar um 'service' e mesmo depois de gerado o service ele dá o mesmo erro!!![image: ![Error generate service]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcdXe.png)

Answer (score 1):

Ao contrário do Ionic 3, o Ionic 4 usa [service e não provider](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/365197/77268)

Segue um exemplo de como criar um service usando o Angular CLI

```
ionic generate service user
```

Comment: Valeu irmão , brigado mesmo!

Comment: Não esqueça de [aceitar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/77268) uma das respostas :)

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
ionic generate provider <name> [options]
```

A partir do IONIC 4 o IONIC CLI mudou algumas sintaxes.